# PYTHON - Failing to import pythoncom

Tags: python, python-3.5, pywin32, pythoncom

I'm a newbie to python (3.5 version) and I installed the mudule pywin32 to my computer. When I try to import pythoncom I get this error.

```
>>> import **pythoncom**
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#0>", line 1, in <module>
    import pythoncom
  File "C:\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\pythoncom.py", line 2, in <module>
    import pywintypes
  File "C:\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\win32\lib\pywintypes.py", line 124, in <module>
    __import_pywin32_system_module__("pywintypes", globals())
  File "C:\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\win32\lib\pywintypes.py", line 98, in __import_pywin32_system_module__
    raise ImportError("No system module '%s' (%s)" % (modname, filename))
ImportError: No system module 'pywintypes' (pywintypes35.dll)
>>>
```

I already reinstalled the pywin32 and also already tried to update it via pip --upgrade command.
My OS is Windows 10.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please use the preview option and code formatting.